# Show Account, Contact, Custom object related date to customer

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-community

I have to show Account, Related Contact, Related Opportunity to customer.

What I have to do is
1) Send an email to contact related to an account e.g abc.ltd through button on contact or account
2) Email will have a link. On hit of link he will get a login page where he can create a user or enter his username, Password
3) On successful login he will see his Account, Contact, Opportunity, Custom  Object etc
4) He can add contact or delete a contact.
5) On click of logout he should get loged out.

I searched for the content and got to know about community user license. I am using a developer account.

Can any body help me to setup the above requirement

Comment: First thing, you shouldn't be using developer edition to handle actual business.

Comment: Ok. Is their a any help doc that i can refer.